# The result of javaML classify is always one thing

Tags: java, machine-learning, svm

I am using javaML to classify my datas.

What I tried is :

Think that I have two category `cat1,cat2` , so I made `Instance` like this:

```
Instance instance = new SparseInstance();
```

Any feature has specific index in both cat1 and cat2 so I use this:

```
//each instance contains one document
instance.put(index,value);
//for example this instance belongs to cat1 
instance.setClassValue("cat1");
dataSet.add(instance);
```

So other `instance` will be added to the `dataSet` like that.

After that I tried to make my `testDataSet` exactly like what I have done for creating `dataSet` for classifier , it means that the indexes are the same but different value

but when i try

```
for (Instance inst : testDataSet) {
   Object predictedClassValue = classifier.classify(inst);
   System.out.println(predictedClassValue);
 }
```

the `predictedClassValue` is always `cat1`

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: This is most probably related to the Machine Learning model called here "classifier", and its incorrect usage. SO is not the good place for asking for such help, you should include more details regarding construction and training of `classifier` and repost this question to ai.stackexchange.com or cross-validated.

Comment: thanks @lejlot but the javaML is a library and it will build the model using data-set , it means that it will create `svm_parameter` and `svm_problem` and i have no control over that , please help me

Comment: i found that `ai.stackexchange.com` is in private beta for at least 1 more day, please tell me what i should include to this question to make?

Comment: First of all: code that you use to construct the `classifier` instance, second of all, you should include "minimal reproducible example", so you should post data for which it happens too.

Comment: Ok, but by data i mean the actual **data files**, not only the code

Comment: i calculate the weight of features using `tf-idf` and after that i select the features using `feature selection algorithms`

Comment: You seem to completely ignore my comments. "To post the data" it means to give us your **data files**, not description of what you are doing :) if anyone is supposed to help, (s)he has to be able to reproduce the problem, this requires the exact same **data**, not just procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your are running svm with some default parameters:

```
svmClassifier.buildClassifier(dataSet);
```

This can lead to the trivial model (answering always "cat1"). Machine learning is not that simple, you have to tune some metaparameters in order to achieve good model. In case of SVM it should be `C` parameter and (in case of RBF/polynomial kernels) also `gamma`. In other words - it seems ok, simply with default parameters your SVM choosed to build a simplest possible solution.

You also do not seem to normalize your data, which can also be a problem for a SVM model. You should at least scale each input dimension into some interval (for example `[-1,1]`).

If none of these help, this would mean that your data is corrupted in some way (maybe it is impossible to actually diversify your classes? Maybe this is simply "contradicting" data?)

Comment: at first i tried to make model using `libSVM` and i scaled the each input dimension into some interval `([-1,1])` but it returned  `cat1` , i thought that maybe my svm_parameters are wrong so i tried to use `javaMl` which will found the best parameter for your dataSet but as you see the result just is `cat1`

Comment: why do you think, that javaML find best parameters **on its own**? I am pretty sure that it does not, and you are doing **exactly the same** what with libsvm

Comment: but in javaML i can's choose parameter and it do it by it self , if it is wrong please show me how  can i do that , and one more thing how we can find the best parameter?

Comment: this is completely false. libsvm (in javaml) object has method "setParameters(libsvm.svm_parameter param)". This is **exactly the same** as in the "pure" libsvm. Nothing is done "by itself". Parameter tuning has been described dozens of time. Simply google for "cross validation parameter tuning/selection". You can try "SelfOptimizingLinearLibSVM" from javaml, which performs internal cross validation

Comment: i returned to the `LIB_SVM`, the parameters was true but the data was corrupted, so i found the problem and made it to work

Answer (score 3):

i had this same problem a while back. The reason for having the same prediction is because of the dataset you are training your LIBSVM  with, not because you are using default parameters. Make sure there are  equal(or almost) amount of data for each "label or classValue" in your data set. That should fix it. eg cat1 = 50 INSTANCE, cat2= 50 INSTANCE